# Proof of Second Order Conditions for Maximization Problem with Two Variables and One Inequality Constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, solution-verification, nonlinear-optimization, economics

### ***Background Information***

I am studying the theorem of S.O.C.s for a constrained maximization problem. Here is the theorem on the book but lack of proof:

> **Theorem**$\space\space\space\space$ Let $f$, $g_1$, $\dots$, $g_m$, $h_1$, $\dots$, $h_k$ be $C^2$ functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the problem of maximizing $f$ on the constraint set
> \begin{equation}
> C_{g, h} \equiv \{\mathbf{x} | g_1(\mathbf{x}) \leq b_1, \dots, g_m(\mathbf{x}) \leq b_m, h_1(\mathbf{x}) = c_1, \dots, h_k(\mathbf{x}) = c_k\}.
> \end{equation}
> Form the Lagrangian
> \begin{equation}
> L(x_1, \dots, x_n, \lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_m, \mu_1, \dots, \mu_k) \\ = f(\mathbf{x}) - \lambda_1(g_1(\mathbf{x}) - b_1) - \dots - \lambda_m(g_m(\mathbf{x}) - b_m) - \mu_1(h_1(\mathbf{x}) - c_1) - \dots - \mu_k(h_k(\mathbf{x}) - c_k)
> \end{equation}
> (a) Suppose that there exist $\lambda_1^{*}, \dots, \lambda_m^{*}, \mu_1^{*}, \dots, \mu_k^{*}$ such that the following F.O.C.s hold at $(\mathbf{x}^*, \lambda^*, \mu^*)$:
> \begin{equation}
> \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1} = 0, \dots, \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_n} = 0,\\
> \lambda_1^{*} \geq 0, \dots, \lambda_m^{*} \geq 0,\\
> \lambda_1^{*}(g_1(\mathbf{x}^*) - b_1) = 0, \dots, \lambda_m^{*}(g_m(\mathbf{x}^*) - b_m) = 0,\\
> h_1(\mathbf{x}^*) = c_1, \dots, h_k(\mathbf{x}^*) = c_k.
> \end{equation}
> (b) For notation's sake, suppose that $g_1, \dots, g_e$ are binding at $\mathbf{x}^*$ and $g_{e + 1}, \dots, g_m$ are not binding. Write $(g_1, \dots, g_e)$ as $\mathbf{g}_E$. Suppose that the Hessian of $L$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}$ at $(\mathbf{x}^*, \lambda^*, \mu^*)$ is negative definite on the linear constraint set
> \begin{equation}
> \{\mathbf{v} | D\mathbf{g}_E(\mathbf{x})^*\mathbf{v} = 0 \space and\space Dh(\mathbf{x}^*)\mathbf{v} = 0\};
> \end{equation}
> that is,
> \begin{equation}
> \mathbf{v} \neq 0,\space D\mathbf{g}_E(\mathbf{x})^*\mathbf{v} = 0,\space Dh(\mathbf{x}^*)\mathbf{v} = 0\space \Longrightarrow\space \mathbf{v}^T \cdot (D_{\mathbf{x}}^2L(\mathbf{x}^*, \lambda^*, \mu^*)) \cdot \mathbf{v} < 0.
> \end{equation}
> Then, $\mathbf{x}^*$ is a strict local constrained max of $f$ on $C_{g, h}$

### ***Problem***

The question asks for a complete proof of the above theorem for case of two variables and one *inequality* constraint.

### ***My Attempt to Rewrite The Theorem***

So here is my attempt. Instead of going directly to prove the theorem of the special case, I choose to rewrite the theorem for the case of two variables and one *inequality* constraint. But I got some trouble when rewriting the theorem for this special case. Since there is only one *inequality* constraint, whether it is binding or not makes difference. I cannot find a way to prove it in a general manner, like the statement in the theorem. Therefore, I rewrite the theorem as the following and I want to prove it case by case:

> **Theorem**$\space\space\space\space$ Let $f$, $g$ be $C^2$ functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the problem of maximizing $f$ on the constraint set
> \begin{equation}
> C_{g} \equiv \{(x, y) | g(x, y) \leq b\}.
> \end{equation}
> Form the Lagrangian
> \begin{equation}
> L(x, y, \lambda) = f(x, y) - \lambda(g(x, y) - b)
> \end{equation}
> ***Case 1: $g$ is binding at the maximum point $(x^*, y^*)$.***
> (a) Suppose that there exists $\lambda^*$ such that the F.O.C.s are satisfied at $(x^*, y^*, \lambda^*)$; that is
> \begin{equation}
> \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0,\space \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 0,\space \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = 0,\space \lambda \geq 0\space\space at\space\space (x^*, y^*, \lambda^*);\space and\\
> \end{equation}
> (b)
> \begin{equation}
> det
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 0 & \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\\
> \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x \partial y}\\
> \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial y \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial y^2}
> \end{pmatrix}
> > 0\space\space\space\space at\space\space\space\space (x^*, y^*, \lambda^*)
> \end{equation}
> Then, $(x^*, y^*)$ is a strict local constraint max of $f$ on $C_g$.
> ***Case 2: $g$ is not binding at the maximum point $(x^*, y^*)$.***
> (a) Suppose that there exists $\lambda^* = 0$ such that the F.O.C.s are satisfied at $(x^*, y^*, \lambda^*(=0))$; that is
> \begin{equation}
> \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0,\space \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 0,\space \lambda = 0\space\space at\space\space (x^*, y^*, \lambda^*(=0));\space and\\
> \end{equation}
> (b)
> \begin{equation}
> det
> \begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x \partial y}\\
> \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial y \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial y^2}
> \end{pmatrix}
> > 0\space\space and\space\space det
> \begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x^2}
> \end{pmatrix} < 0\space\space at\space\space (x^*, y^*, \lambda^*(=0)).
> \end{equation}
> Then, $(x^*, y^*)$ is a strict local constraint max of $f$ on $C_g$.

I would like to know if my rewriting of the theorem for the special case of two variables and one *inequality* constraint is **(1) correct** and **(2) necessary** for proving the theorem. Could someone please help with it? Thanks a lot in advance!

### ***My Attempt to Prove***

> **Proof of Case 1**$\space\space\space\space$ With single binding inequality constraint, I feel that the theorem reduces to a two variable one *equality* constraint case, except that we must have $\lambda^* \geq 0$ to guarantee that the optimal point is indeed a maximum.

> **Proof of Case 2**$\space\space\space\space$ The proof of case 2 follows from the following theorem:
>
> > **Theorem**$\space\space\space\space$ Let $F:U \to R^1$ be a $C^2$ function whose domain is an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $\mathbf{x}^*$ is a critical point of $F$ in that it satisfies
> > \begin{equation}
> > \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(\mathbf{x}^*) = 0\space\space\space\space for\space\space i = 1, \dots, n.
> > \end{equation}
> > Then, if the Hessian $D^2F(\mathbf{x}^x)$ is a negative definite symmetric matrix, then $\mathbf{x}^*$ is a strict local max of $F$.

I would like to know, if my thoughts are correct. I really appreciate any help!